# Importing GeoJSON File

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geojson

[image][image]I am dragging and dropping this GeoJSON file into QGIS but for some reason I cannot reproject it from WGS 84 (EPSG:4326).  It remains at the original LAT/LONG even in a new project where UTMs are expected.

[image: GEOJSON]

Comment: GeoJSON uses 4326, period. If the cords are not WGS84 geographic, it's not a conforming GeoJSON.

Comment: What steps exactly did you use to reproject?  What format are you outputting? Can you edit your question and link to the actual data?

Comment: http://discoursemedia.org/discourse-interactive/workcamp-map/workcamps.js

Comment: I am dragging and dropping the json file into QGIS.  Not sure what you mean by output.  I just want the data projected correctly in QGIS.  I am looking to reproject it to BCAlbers 3005, but just getting it to import correctly into 4326 would be a start.

Comment: @vince GeoJSON doesn't use EPSG:4326 it uses CRS:84 (different axis order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GeoJSON specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-7 the coordinates should be in order lon lat. Your data seems to have order lat lon.